# Не работает запрос в базу при подтверждении активационного ключа

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть **код активации ключа аккаунта**, который отправляется на **почту пользователя**, но когда дело доходит до **запроса в базу данных**, то **ничего не происходит**.

Сам код:

```
<?php
    include('sql.php');
    include('token.php');

    if (isset($_COOKIE['token'])) {
        $user = fetchUserToken($mysql, $_COOKIE['token']);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['key_submit'])) {
        $activate = $_POST['key'];

        if ($activate != $user['activate-email']) {
            echo 'Введённый Вами ключ не совпадает с активационным ключом!';
            exit();
        } else {
            header('Location: /');
            $db = "UPDATE `accounts` SET `status` = 1 WHERE `activate-email` = :activate";
            $par = ["activate-email" => $activate];
            $mysql->prepare($db)->execute($par);
        }
    }
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
      <h5>Письмо выслано на почту вашего аккаунта!</h5>
      <p>Проверяйте письмо в разделе "Спам"</p>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column w-100 gap-2">
           <label for="newsletter1" class="visually-hidden"></label>
           <input name="key" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Активационный ключ">
           <button name="key_submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Отправить</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего надо заменить

```
$par = ["activate-email" => $activate];
```

на

```
$par = [":activate" => $activate];
```

А в целом используйте вывод ошибок на страницу, чтобы интерпретатор показал в чём именно дело

[Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482)

Comment: Я использую PDO и в PDO-запросе переменная $activate будет правильно писаться :activate

Comment: @Sergey3423 Не путайте шаблон (placeholder) и переменную со значением, которое должно быть подставлено на место этого шаблона. Похожесть имени им нафиг не нужна.

Comment: @Sergey3423 ответили выше